# Trigger script only when user press in submit button

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I am executing a script through a function

```html
<script language="javascript">
  function showVariantDetail(str) {
    url = "insurancemodel.php?ncvd=" + str;
    getRequest(url, "txtVariantDetails");
  }
</script>
```

The script is executing perfectly through

```
<div id="txtVariantDetails">
</div>
```

But i want the script to execute when the user press in submit button

```html
<div class="search-box-left"></div>
<div class="search-box-right">
  <input name="" type="submit" value="Calculate" class="red-btn" />
</div>
```

can anyone guide on how to ensure when only the user presses in submit button then the `txtVariantDetails`  script to be processed only

Thanks

Comment: `click` or `submit` handler? https://api.jquery.com/click/ or https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: `Form` will be helpful

Comment: @Ruchika So you want `showVariantDetail` to execute when user presses submit button? If so, how does your form tag look like?

Answer (score 0):

try jquery on click

```
$('#submitDemo').on("click",function() {
  // your stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use click handler for the submit input.

```
$("input[type=submit]").on("click",function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  showVariantDetail(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to deal with jQuery:

```js
let redButton = document.querySelector(".red-btn");
redButton.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let buttonValue = redButton.value;
    showVariantDetails(buttonValue);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change **Html** Like below

```
<div class="search-box-left"></div>
<div class="search-box-right">
  <input type="button" value="Calculate" class="red-btn" />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script language="javascript">
  function showVariantDetail(str) {
    url = "insurancemodel.php?ncvd=" + str;
    getRequest(url, "txtVariantDetails");
  }
$(document).on('click','.red-btn',function() {
// var str="" //get your string here
  showVariantDetail(str)
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, although code seems like perfect one, but somehow is not executing. Is anything to mention on commented - // var str="" //get your string here

Comment: @Ruchika `str` is your input string. need to get by `id` or `class`. like `$('.classname').val();`

Comment: S - somehow still not able to execute. But when using through<div id="txtVariantDetails">
</div> is executing perfectly.